# How to get .pfx file for renewed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

We have a SSL certificate associated with a .dev domain purchased from GoDaddy about 2 years ago. The domain is associated with a website hosted in Azure, the initial certificate was uploaded as a .pfx file.
After a year the certificate expired, GoDaddy renewed it automatically but it was not installed on the server (the .dev domain is not really used). 
Now the certificate was renewed again automatically by GoDaddy and I was tasked to install it again on the server. From GoDaddy I can download the certificate as a zip file (it contains 3 files, a .crt, a .p7b an a .pem) but it is only the public key, I do not have a private key as the certificate was renewed automatically, so the installed certificate on my computer cannot be exported as .pfx. 
I generated a new CSR file using DigiCert Util app and I submitted a Re-Key request to GoDaddy for the certificate. I got a new certificate from GoDaddy, I installed it on the local machine where I generated the CSR but the new certificate still cannot be exported as .pfx.
What do I need to do in order to get a full certificate that can be exported as .pfx?

Comment: you need to have cert and private key to export to pfx, what is your web server and OS? are you trying to export using DigiCert Util https://www.digicert.com/kb/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm if you have key and cert you can export to pfx with openssl or some other tool, e.g. openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey private.key -in cert.cer

Comment: I generated a CSR with DigiCert Util so I assume the private key have been created somewhere on my computer (Win 10 Pro). Using the CSR I re-keyed the certificate with GoDaddy. I downloaded the new certificate from GoDaddy, imported it on my machine, I still cannot export it as .pfx, I assume the existing private key has not been matched to imported certificate but I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using OpenSSL. I generated a new key and CSR using OpenSSL, I re-keyed the certificate with GoDaddy and then using OpenSSL I merged the private key with the certificate downloaded from GoDaddy and got the .pfx file.